# Element h5 not allowed as child of element span in this context

Tags: css, html

i have the code

```
<span>
<h5>Standard Page Template</h5>
<ul>
<li>1 Design Concepts</li>
<li>1 Free Round of Revisions</li>
<li>5 Day Turnaround</li>
<li>Photoshop Source File</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

and its css as

```
#specs .type .prices a:hover span h5 {
color:#09f;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
top:3px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline;
position:relative;
}
```

i am getting the following error

"Element h5 not allowed as child of element span in this context" and
"Element ul not allowed as child of element span in this context"

please help me.

Comment: spans are not meant to be used as content wrappers. It will work, but it doesn't comply with w3 standards. Change the span to a div, and add `display:inline-block;` to the css of the div to make it like a span.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ul` and `h5` are block-level elements, but `span` is an inline element. Inline elements can be placed iside block elements, but block elements cannot be placed in inline elements. The block-level equivalent for `span` is `div`. Use a `div` instead.

Note that in HTML5, the principle is mostly the same but there are more [content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models) than just block and inline.

Comment: Note that an exception to this rule *in HTML5* is that `<a>` tags, which are inline elements, can accept block element children. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12659766/1883647).

Comment: do i need to change the css too.

Comment: in css do i need to change it to div instead of span

Comment: div worked, but now i have visual problem on my page. can i use anything else instead of div?

Comment: Not really. Just fix the problem with CSS. Try the recommended `display: inline-block;` on the `div`